# File || Stream processing vs Normal processing memory consumption

Tags: java, nio

I need to find out amt of memory saved using stream processing vs conventional reading whole file in memory

I have tried 2 tests .Case 1 .Commented stream part
Case 2 : Commented Normal processing part

```
//Normal process
        List<String> lines1 =Files.readAllLines(wiki_path);     
      for (String string : lines1) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
//

      /* Stream process
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(wiki_path);
        System.out.println("<!-----Read all lines as a Stream-----!>");     //Stream processing
        lines.forEach(System.out :: println);
        lines.close();
     */
```

Amt of memory used is 36 MB for both normal as well as stream processing .Why is there no difference in memory consumption between both approaches File size is 8.5mb

Memory calculated using runtime.totalMemory()-runtime.freeMemory()

Note :: if i comment for loops for both the test cases ,result is showing difference of around 25 mb i.e stream process consumes only 4 mb ,whereas normal consumes 29 mb.
Why is it not the same after adding for loops in both test cases ?

Comment: I'm confused. First you say there is no difference, then you say there is 25 mb difference. Which is it?

Comment: Normal uses more memory because it **loads the entire file** into memory, and the text in memory is likely twice the size of the text in the file, because Java stores text in UTF-16. So if file is 1 gb, then code would use more than 2 gb of memory. --- Streaming only **keeps one line in memory**, so memory consumption is proportional to the longest line. Which means that a 1 gb file would likely not consume any more memory. --- Of course, memory management in Java is a complex thing, so the above is just guidelines. Exactly memory use will vary.

Comment: @Andreas : Difference is not found in memory consumption if "for loops" are kept in both cases .If I remove for loops while executing the same ,Streaming shows up as verymuch efficient. Why is that after adding For loops i.e Printing each line ,removing this efficiency of Streaming  ?

Comment: In the second case, all strings are also loaded in memory. The difference is that they're loaded one after the other, and not all at once. So **if** the JVM needs to reclaim memory and decides to start a garbage collection, then it can reclaim all the memory that was allocated for the previously read strings. That's not the case with the first solution, since all strings are references by the list and can thus not be garbage collected.

Comment: Try both solutions with, for example, a file of 500MB and a head limited to 256MB. The first solution will throw an OutOfMemoryError, and the second one will work fine.